# Как конвертировать pdf в word?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, libre-office

Нужно это сделать через консоль, система Debian 9

```
sudo libreoffice --invisible --convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" 1.pdf
```

Не работает, выдает ошибку

```
convert /var/www/trash/data/www/site/1.pdf -> /var/www/trash/data/www/site/1.docx using filter : MS Word 2007 XML
Error: Please verify input parameters... (SfxBaseModel::impl_store <file:///var/www/trash/data/www/site/1.docx> failed: 0xc10)
```

Уже что только не пробовал, не работает.

```
sudo libreoffice --invisible --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export 2.docx
```

Работает хорошо.
Подскажите как конвертировать правильно.
Спасибо.

Comment: Зачем sudo-то?.

Comment: Но вообще нельзя просто так взять и конвертировать pdf в doc/docx/odt, потому что формат pdf очень сильно отличается от них своим внутренним устройством, и качественно свёрстанного docx-файла вы в любом случае не получите и замучаетесь с ним работать. Возможно, именно поэтому libreoffice и не поддерживает прямое конвертирование из pdf